# Issue in creating combobox dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to create a ComboBox dynamically, but cannot create it.
Here is the code that I wrote.

```
        ComboBox com_dynamic = new ComboBox();            
        com_dynamic.Height = 50;
        com_dynamic.Width = 100;           
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(com_dynamic);           
        tb.Margin = new Thickness(0, 145, 87, 0);
        tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;

        ComboBoxItem com_dynamic_item = new ComboBoxItem();
        com_dynamic.AddChild(com_dynamic_item);
        com_dynamic_item.Content = "item1";
```

Comment: woah...!!! one edit changes the whole meaning of your code!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should also add the combobox to a container control. If you want to add it in the `LayoutRoot`, then this is the line you are missing.

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(com_dynamic);
```

You can reposition the combobox using its margin in the container.