# exception in add combobox item

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to add item dynamically to ComboBox.

but it throw the exeption "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead".

[image]

```
namespace Trainning
```

{

```
public partial class ComboBox : Window
{
    int intex_count;

    public ComboBox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();         

        add_items();


    }

    public List<object> add_items()
    {
        List<object> items = new List<object>();

        items.Add("chandru");
        items.Add(83);

        com_add_remove.ItemsSource = items;
        com_add_remove.SelectedIndex = 0;

        return items;
    }
 private void btn_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        com_add_remove.Items.Add(txt_item.Text);
         intex_count = com_add_remove.Items.Count;
        com_add_remove.SelectedIndex = intex_count - 1;

    }
```

Comment: you can't put source and changes at the same time if you wish to do and do changes in source and simple make that source updatable as like observablecollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use `ItemsSource`, you can't also add items manually to the same component. So you have to either use `ItemsSouce` ***or*** add and remove items manually.

I would go with `ItemsSource`, and to the following change:

replace:

```
com_add_remove.Items.Add(txt_item.Text);
```

with:

```
items.Add(txt_item.Text);
```

That means you have to add items as a class variable instead of just a local variable inside the add_items method so that you can reference it from `btn_add_Click` as well.

Your other option is to change the add_items method so add items istead of using `ItemsSource`:

replace:

```
com_add_remove.ItemsSource = items;
```

with:

```
items.ForEach( i => com_add_remove.Items.Add(i));
```

Comment: please Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen see these links. .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880229/issue-in-creating-combobox-dynamically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877616/how-to-use-on-screen-keyboard-in-whole-window. i posted  a question here.i know well you only the right person to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have bound your combobox to some sort of data source after that you should only change the data source.

You need to declare the `List<object> items = new List<object>();` in your class and just add and remove items from the list. Your combobox will automatically be updated.

```
public partial class ComboBox : Window
{
  int intex_count;
  List<object> items;
  public ComboBox()
  {
    this.InitializeComponent();         



    //key_value();

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Height = 50;
    tb.Width = 100;
    tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(tb);
    tb.Text = "Dynamic TextBox";
    tb.Margin = new Thickness(0, 145, 87, 0);
    tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    tb.Padding = new Thickness(15, 15, 15, 15); //to center the textbox's text  

    items = new List<object>();
    add_items();
    com_add_remove.ItemsSource = items;
    com_add_remove.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

public List<object> add_items()
{
    //List<object> items = new List<object>();

    items.Add("chandru");
    items.Add(83);        

    return items;
}

private void btn_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     items.Remove(txt_item.Text);
     intex_count = items.Count;

}
```