# how to bind the button content where mouse selection is start

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="storyboard.clear"
x:Name="Window"
Title="clear"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="btn_a" Content="A" Height="56" Margin="208,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Click="btn_a_Click" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_display" Height="50" Margin="208,57,252,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_b" Content="B" Height="56" Margin="297,149,252,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn_b_Click" />
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class clear : Window
{
    public clear()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();         

    }

    private void btn_a_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_display.Text += btn_a.Content.ToString();
        txt_display.SelectionStart = txt_display.Text.Length;
        txt_display.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_display.Text += btn_b.Content.ToString();
        txt_display.SelectionStart = txt_display.Text.Length;
        txt_display.Focus();
    }
}
```

[image]

here i want to bind the button content where the mouse selection is starting like above figure.

but i can't resolve this scenario.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but are you trying to insert the content of the button at the cursor location in the textbox? If that's the case, you will need to get the caret index of the TextBox to determine where to insert.

```
private void btn_a_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var caretIndex = txt_display.CaretIndex;
    txt_display.Text =txt_display.Text.Insert(caretIndex, btn_a.Content.ToString());
    txt_display.SelectionStart = txt_display.Text.Length;
    txt_display.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Hoang, you are correct.I've got what i need.i've just forgot to mention one thing.the cursor is moved right corner of the textbox after i bind the text.but cursor selection has to start after the text what i bind until i change the cursor selection.pls help me...

Comment: In that case just set the caret to be one after the current caret index. `var caretIndex = txt_display.CaretIndex;
            txt_display.Text = txt_display.Text.Insert(caretIndex, btn_a.Content.ToString());
            txt_display.Focus();
            txt_display.CaretIndex = caretIndex + 1;`

Comment: Hoang please take a look to these links .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880229/issue-in-creating-combobox-dynamically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877616/how-to-use-on-screen-keyboard-in-whole-window. i posted a questioh here.i hope that you only right person to resolve that problem... please do this fever..

Answer (score 0):

You should try to be more specific with what you want to do.  Assuming that you have exactly two buttons and you want their content to be in sync with the first and second letter to the right of the caret position of the TextBox, you could create an event for the TextBox SelectionChanged event like so:

```
    private void txtbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btn != null)
        {
            string letters = txtbox.Text.Substring(txtbox.SelectionStart);

            if (letters.Length > 0)
                btn.Content = letters[0];

            if (letters.Length > 1)
                btn2.Content = letters[1];
        }
    }
```

In this case if you had a TextBox with the text inside it "Hello World!" and the caret position is to the left of the **d**, then buttons would display the text "d" and "!" respectively.